Recover signal from single-sided spectrum using ifft
I am trying to recover a signal by inverse Fourier-transforming the single-sided spectrum, but I am getting the wrong result. I do successfully transform the single-sided spectrum back to double-sided spectrum but from there I get lost. What am I doing wrong here? In fact, how can I recover the full information after doing abs(), isn't there lost info there?
Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
L = 1500;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector
S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
X = S + 2*randn(size(t));
figure(1)
plot(1000*t(1:50),X(1:50))
title("Signal Corrupted with Zero-Mean Random Noise")
xlabel("t (milliseconds)")
ylabel("X(t)")

Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
figure(2)
plot(f,P1) 
title("Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)")
xlabel("f (Hz)")
ylabel("|P1(f)|")

X2=ifft(Y);
figure(3)
plot(X2(1:50))
Y2 = 2*[P1(1) P1(2:end)/2 fliplr(conj(P1(2:end)))/2];
X3 = ifft(L*Y2);
figure(4)
plot(Y2)
figure(5)
plot(X3(1:50))

The reason why I need to recover the signal from the single-sided spectrum is that I need to take derivatives (multiply by 1i*kx the fourier-transform, with kx the wavenumber)

Do you only have the magnitude information or do you also have the phase? As your Y is complex so  Y2 needs to be. So having the magnitude and phase would allow you to generate the complex values. Have look at fft-images-and-its-inverse, it is a 2D example but it is mainly the same for 1D

You do not need to take the absolute value of the DFT coefficients for what you are trying to do. You need the whole information, and the phase is important. Does it not give you your signal back when you do X2=ifft(Y);? If you really want to use the single-side spectrum just extract it as S=Y(1:L/2+1)

Apart from already commented issue in P2 = abs(Y/L) some other suggestions are - Instead of plot(X3(1:50)) change it to plot(abs(X3(1:50))), as ifft will give complex vector. As your input has complex conjugate symmetry imaginary coefficient of X3 are 0 (in this case e-19, e-20 range). Also I don't think in 2*[P1(1) P1(2:end)/2 fliplr(conj(P1(2:end)))/2] multiplication by 2 is required.
With these changes I can see exact match in original and reconstructed time signal.
